# Django Managers - Retrieving objects with non-empty set of related objects

Tags: django, orm

I have two classes, Portfolio, and PortfolioImage.

```
class PortfolioImage(models.Model):
    portfolio     = models.ForeignKey('Portfolio', related_name='images')
    ...

class Portfolio(models.Model):
    def num_images(self):
        return self.images.count()
```

I want to write a "non-empty portfolio" manager for Portfolio, so that I can do:

```
queryset = Portfolio.nonempty.all()
```

I've tried doing something like this, but I don't think this is even close:

```
class NonEmptyManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(NonEmptyManager, self).get_query_set().filter(num_images > 0)
```

I don't really know where to start, and I'm finding the documentation a bit lacking in this area.

Any ideas? Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all according to [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups) you cannot use model methods for lookup with `filter`/`exclude` clause. Then also you cannot use python operators (`>` in your case) with `filter`/`exclude`.

To resolve your task if you are using Django 1.1beta:

```
from django.db.models import Count

#...

def get_query_set(self):
    return super(NonEmptyManager,self).get_query_set()\
      .annotate(num_images=Count('images'))\
      .filter(num_images__gt=0)
```

But this solution has some limitations.

Another way for Django >= 1.0:

```
def get_query_set(self):
    return super(NonEmptyManager,self).get_query_set()\
      .filter(images__isnull=True)
```